# Can we add network param to run function to verify contract on specific network?

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, typescript

I am trying to create a task for deploying and verifying any contract from my project..
task below successfully deployed contract but it is not able to verify..

How can i tell `hre.run` function to run the verify task on network passed in taskArgs

Getting following error

```
**Error in plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify: The selected network is "hardhat", which is not supported for contract verification. Please choose a network supported by Etherscan.**

If you intended to use a different network, ensure that you provide the --network parameter when running the command.     

For example: npx hardhat verify --network <network-name>
```

**Command i am running** ->

```
npx hardhat deploy-and-verify --contract Informant --chain mumbai
```

**Code for task -**

```
import { task } from "hardhat/config";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
require("dotenv").config();
import {getContractArgs} from './costructorArgs';
import { getProviderURLs } from "./getProviderURL";

task("deploy-and-verify", "Deployes and verifies a contract to any network")
    .addParam("contract", "The name of contract")
    .addParam("chain", "Network to deploy")
    .setAction(async(taskArgs, hre : HardhatRuntimeEnvironment)=>{

    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(await getProviderURLs(taskArgs.chain));
    const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "", provider);

    const { abi, bytecode } = await hre.artifacts.readArtifact(taskArgs.contract);
    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);

    const contract = await factory.deploy(
        ...await getContractArgs(taskArgs.contract, taskArgs.chain)
    );

    await contract.deploymentTransaction();
    
    console.log(`
 Successfully deployed ${taskArgs.contract} contract on ${taskArgs.chain}.
 Contract address: ${contract.target}`);

    console.log(`Now, let's verify the contract ${taskArgs.contract} at ${taskArgs.chain} explorer`);

    await hre.run("verify", {
        address: await contract.getAddress(),
        constructorArguments: await getContractArgs(taskArgs.contract, taskArgs.chain)
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution.. I created seperate tasks and then kind of used them in single task...

As per @Jaskaran Singh 's Answer.. it's correct to use --network param straight away as it is provided already by hardhat.

1. Deploy-verify.ts

```
import { task, types } from "hardhat/config";
import { getContractArgs } from "./utils/costructorArgs";
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

task("deploy-verify", "Deploys NFT, Verify on etherscan, and send airdrop")
    .addParam("contract", "name of contract")
    .addParam("chain","network to deploy")
    .setAction(async (_args, hre) => {
        const contractName = _args.contract
        const chain = _args.chain
        const contractAddress = await hre.run("deploy", {contract:contractName, chain:chain})
        const contract = _args.contract;
        await hre.run("verify-contract", { address:contractAddress,contract: contract, constructorArguments:await getContractArgs(contractName, chain), chain:chain })
});
```

2.deploy.ts

```
import { task } from "hardhat/config";
import { getContractArgs } from "./utils/costructorArgs";
import { getProviderURLs } from "./utils/getProviderURL";

task("deploy", "Deploys NFT Smart contract")
.addParam("contract", "contract name")
.addParam("chain","network to deploy").setAction(
  async (taskArgs, hre) => {
    await hre.run("compile");

    const provider = new hre.ethers.JsonRpcProvider(await getProviderURLs(taskArgs.chain));
    
    const [signer] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();;

    const { abi, bytecode } = await hre.artifacts.readArtifact(taskArgs.contract);
    const factory = new hre.ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);

    const contract = await factory.deploy(
        ...await getContractArgs(taskArgs.contract, taskArgs.chain)
    );

    await contract.waitForDeployment();

    await contract.deploymentTransaction()?.wait(5);
    
    console.log(`
 Successfully deployed contract on ${taskArgs.chain}.
 Contract address: ${contract.target}`);

    return contract.target
  }
);
```

3.Verify.ts

```
import { task, types } from "hardhat/config";
import { getContractArgs } from "./utils/costructorArgs";

task("verify-contract", "Verify deployed contract on Etherscan")
    .addParam("contract", "name of contract")
    .addParam("address", "Contract address deployed", undefined, types.string)
    .addParam("chain", "chain to deploy")
    .setAction(async (_args,hre) => {
    try {
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: _args.address,
            contract: `contracts/${_args.contract}.sol:${_args.contract}`,
            constructorArguments: await getContractArgs(_args.contract, _args.chain)
        })
    } catch (message) {
        console.error(message)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can run --network to deploy and verify the smart contract . I would suggest you build two scripts one for deployment and one for verification . You can use this command for deployment `npx hardhat run "path of script" --network "network name"`.

Comment: Thank you, @JasKaran Singh , For my usecase, it is better to have single task. Initially i thought when we create custom task we can't use env params by hardhat. but later tried --network and it worked.